# How to pull all strings from a lists of lists that contain a certain character?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, sublist

I have the following lists of lists and I'd like all strings within the list of lists that contain the "|" character.

```
 l = [['a','b','c|','d'],['1|','|2','3|','4'],['1|','2','3|','4','']]
```

Results:

```
l =  ['c|', '1|', '3|', '1|', '3|']
```

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Regular expressions are not needed to simply look for a substring.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use regular expression:

```
>>> l = [['a','b','c|','d'],['1|','2','3|','4'],['1|','2','3|','4','']]
>>> [x for xs in l for x in xs if x.endswith('|')]
['c|', '1|', '3|', '1|', '3|']
>>> [x for xs in l for x in xs if '|' in x]
['c|', '1|', '3|', '1|', '3|']
```

Comment: that's a clever way of doing it. I like it

Answer (score 0):

Using filter:

```
filter(lambda x: "|" in x, sum(l, []))
```

(`sum(l, [])` sums the sublists into one big list)